# Java Class file and method binding

Tags: java, methods

```
public class Bike {
 void run() {
   System.out.println("bike is running");
 }
}

public class Honda extends Bike{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Honda h = new Honda();
   h.run(); // output 'bike is running'
 }
}
```

I tried to see the class file for Honda class and below is the bytecode for the main method

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1
     0: new           #1                  // class newpackage/Honda
     3: dup
     4: invokespecial #16                 // Method "<init>":()V
     7: astore_1
     8: aload_1
     9: invokevirtual #17                 // Method run:()V
    12: return
```

At line 9 the method to be invoked is specified and #17 entry in the constant pool is resolved as follows

```
#17 = Methodref          #1.#18         // newpackage/Honda.run:()V
#18 = NameAndType        #19:#6         // run:()V
```

I was expecting #17 to resolve to Bike.run and not Honda.run since at compile time the information that run method is present in the parent class was available.
What is happening here?

Comment: Conjecture on my part: to support HotSpot swapping #17 Honda.run is a synonym for Bike.run.  But if an implementation of of Honda.run was suddenly available (without a JVM restart) then the bytecode doesn't need to be changed.  #17 now points to the Honda.run implementation instead of being a synonym to Bike.run.  So the JVM's vtable is updated instead of the bytecode needing to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

The base classes may change without the subclass being recompiled.

To execute the method, it doesn't matter where `run()` is declared at runtime, as long as there still is such an *inherited* method. (If not, you'll get `NoSuchMethodError`)

If compiler had defined #17 as `Bike.run()`, the code would have depended too heavily on the `Bike` class.

Comment: So at run time when JVM reaches line 9 it finds invokevirtual and goes to #17 and sees that it resolves to `Honda.run()` and tries to find `run()` method in the Honda class and when it doesn't find it the JVM starts searching the parent classes for the `run()` method?

Comment: @cloud Yes. Read the specification of [`invokevirtual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual) for more detail.